# How to show an editable itab in a popup?

Tags: abap, alv, dynpro, sap-erp

I have an editable ALV buttons (via `status gui`), `SAVE`, `REFRESH`, and `HISTORICAL`.

[image]

I don't have any problem with `save` and `refresh`, but in `historical` i would like to show via popup an itab, but this itab needs to be editable or at least have any button to update changes.

It's important ***not to use*** a custom `dynpro` in this case. So, is there any FM to fill that requirements?

Thanks!

**Edit**:

Ok, it seems i will have to use a `table control` via `dynpro`.
I leave the issue unresolved to post my solution when I have it done

Comment: editable ALVs are usually intended for DB updates, what is the sense of editable itab? you want to reflect these popup changes in the ALV? or they will be saved to DB?

Comment: Yes, that itab will update a posteriori a table from DB with content previously charged referencing items like ```sy-uname```, ```sy-datum```, ```sy-uzeit ``` and the content from coulmn ```Devaluat``` (from screenshot) where its content is different to the itab. (Just a history content table)

Comment: I don't understand why you "must not use a custom `dynpro`", which is the recommended way to create a modal dialog. If you don't want one, you may generate an **amodal** dialog box by instantiating `CL_GUI_DIALOGBOX_CONTAINER` and include the editable ALV inside it. I guess you have many examples in the Web. Amodal means that the user may continue to interact with the current modal dialog (and other amodal ones). If you want only a modal dialog, you must use a dynpro, so I let you search for a generic dynpro designed for this purpose. SAP doesn't propose a standard one as far as I know.

Comment: @SandraRossi There are a lot of function modules for common kinds of modal dialogs, like `POPUP_TO_CONFIRM` or `POPUP_TO_GET_ONE_VALUE`. So this is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Philipp As I said, what you mention does not answer the question, and what I meant about what SAP provides, is that there is no "official" API provided to embed a GUI Control. If the OP wants something not official, then it's possible to use of CL_SCREEN_FRAMEWORK and its related classes, but it's complex to explain how it works. I forgot to mention another solution which is based on the Dynpro technology, but it concerns the Selection Screen which is generated by ABAP statements. If the OP accepts a solution based on "generated Dynpro", I would be happy to post the detailed answer.

Comment: Finally that change was deprecated by my boss and I didn't code that. Sorry guys!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the good old FM `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY` and pass some values to these parameters?

```
i_screen_start_column         = 5  " X0
i_screen_start_line           = 5  " Y0
i_screen_end_column           = 60 " X1
i_screen_end_line             = 20 " Y1
```

*(values are for example)*

And in the fieldcat you should set up these flags to make the column editable.

```
ls_fieldcat-checkbox  = abap_true.
ls_fieldcat-edit      = abap_true.
```